# Prestashop 1.5. The selected value of attributes changes to other value

Tags: prestashop

I have a big problem in my prestashop 1.5.2.0.

In product page, when a user selects a value to an attribute, and then moves on and selects a value in the next attribute, the first selected value changes.

It seems like it mostly is when the last value is selected it changes to the first.

I dont think it has to do with products being in stock, because we tried setting a large no. in stock on them.

We also tried changing the selector between, color picker, dropdown and radio, but it makes no different.

It is not on all products, and it is not only on products with many variants, or with few.

We tried many things but cant find a solution :/

Se the problem for your self:
Go to: http://jkofficeline.dk/85-bordplade-med-centerbue.html
Select 200x100 in "Pladestr."
then select color green in "pladefarver".
Se that "pladestr." changes to 120x80.

or
http://jkofficeline.dk/66-skillev%C3%A6g.html
Select "størrelse": 180x100,
se that "fod" changes from "ingen" to0 "2"

And this occurs many places in different ways.

I hope someone can help!

Thanks

// Sara

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. So fore the sake of others that might have the same problem here is the solution...

The bug occurs when you do not set an url on attributes and values. I dont know if this is basic knowledge, but the url field is not required so we did not fill it out... Which led to that big problem in our shop...

Answer (score 0):

When you create a product attribute in BO: Catalog - attributes and values. Where you set the name and public name. You also have the option to set an URL yourself. The field is not required, and I did not set any URL.
That caused a lot of problems in my shop...